# fire css change before end of code

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm sure this question has already been asked, but I can't found the good keyword to feed google with. I can't even find a good title for my question.
I want to do this :

```
$(".selector").click(function() {
    $(this).css("background-color", "red");
    if (confirm("Do you want to do this ?") {
        // do this
    } else {
        $(this).css("background-color", "transparent");
    }
});
```

But the css change is fired only after I confirm. How can I fire it before the confirm (or during the confirm) ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll bet it's just a simple matter of adding a delay (even just 0 milliseconds). That will ensure that the page repaints before the confirm message appears.

```
$(".selector").click(function() {
    $(this).css("background-color", "red");
    var _this = this;
    function confirmCode(){
        if (confirm("Do you want to do this ?") {
            // do this
        } else {
            $(_this).css("background-color", "transparent");
        }
    }
    setTimeout(function(){confirmCode()}, 0)
});
```

Edit: added complete code

Comment: it works ! I was hoping a solution without the need of another function, with maybe some jquery magic, but I suppose this is a javascript limitation. Actually, I don't need the repaints before the confirm message appears. I could be "during" the confirm dialog. But even if I wait 1 hour, it will never repaint until I click ok, and the code is terminated.

Comment: @Matthieu Yeah, it's a consistent browser quirk with CSS. Any dialog with any CSS change requires this unfortunately.

Comment: Dont need to pass setTimeout a new function, can call it like so: setTimeout(confirmConde, 0);

Comment: @robrich The anonymous function makes sure that the call remains in scope. I'm pretty sure if it isn't used, `setTimeout` assumes the function is global (or more accurately, a member of `window`).

Comment: @JeffreySweeney Good catch, you are correct.  No wrapper function, it looks in global scope.  In this case, you could just put the entire confirmCode function into setTimeout -- nothing else uses it.